# What is indirect buffer and indirect descriptor?

Tags: data-structures, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, linux-device-driver

Recently I'm reading virtio code in linux kernel. I came across "indirect buffer" and "indirect descriptor" in the source code. I wonder what is the meaning of "indirect"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably come across *virtqueue* concept. *virtqueue* ring has a certain (limited) *capacity*, and, since some devices may work way more effective by concurrently dispatching a large number of large requests, *indirect descriptor* feature comes in handy to allow this kind of operation. The idea is simply to increase ring capacity, and this is achieved by storing an *indirect descriptor* **table** *anywhere* in memory and inserting *its* desciptor in main virtqueue (`INDIRECT` flag is set on such a descriptor to show its nature). So, when such *indirect* descriptor is processed in the main ring, control is passed to the *indirect descriptor* **table** (which resides in memory buffer described by `addr` and `len` of that *indirect descriptor* in the main ring). Then descriptors from within such a *table* get processed, and the end of the *table* is determined by absence of `NEXT` flag in the current descriptor. When the flag is found unset, control is passed back to the *virtqueue*.

So, roughly, it's just a trick to "substitute" an ordinary descriptor in the ring by a handful of descriptors thus increasing overall capacity. So, *indirect descriptor* - is an ordinary descriptor in the ring which has `INDIRECT` flag set and which references an *indirect buffer*. The latter is a chunk of memory which contains a *table* of ordinary descriptors to be processed.

Also please note descriptors from within *indirect descriptor table* can't be indirect themselves.